# Keep fixed table row's height after changing table's height

Tags: html-table, row, internet-explorer-7

I have a table with no height defined and three table rows inside.
Example:

```
<table>
 <tr height="20px"> <td> &nbsp; </td> </tr>
 <tr height="1px"> <td> content with unknown height </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td> &nbsp; </td> </tr>
</table>
```

I want the first row to have a fixed 20px height, the second row to expand to it's content's height and the third one to fill the remaining space.

When I change the height of the table in Javascript I want to keep that layout (20px - content height - remaining space), but in IE7 (and probably 6) the rows are scalled to maintain the initial proportions.

Example:

If I had an initial 100px table with 60px content:

Row 1 - 20px

Row 2 - 60px

Row 3 - 20px

and changed it's height to 200px, I would get:

- Any browser/version except IE6/7:

Row 1 - 20px

Row 2 - 60px

Row 3 - 120px

- IE 6/7:

Row 1 - 40px

Row 2 - 120px

Row 3 - 40px

Can I do anything to fix (in IE7) the height of the rows and let the third one to fill the remaining space, keeping the other 2 fixed.